# How do i download all images from a List<string> with many links for images inside?

Tags: c#

```
private List<string> retrieveImages(string address)
{

    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    List<string> imgList = new List<string>();
    doc.Load(wc.OpenRead(address)); //or whatever HTML file you have 
    HtmlNodeCollection imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]");
    if (imgs == null) return new List<string>();

    foreach (HtmlNode img in imgs)
    {
        if (img.Attributes["src"] == null)
            continue;
        HtmlAttribute src = img.Attributes["src"];

        imgList.Add(src.Value);
        //Image imgDownload = GetImage(src.Value);
        //imgDownload.Save(@"d:\myImages");
    }
    return imgList;
}
```

In some case the List imgList contain 33 items and it looks like that:

In the first place `[0]` I see: `/images/experiments/nav_logo78.png`   as a link for the image I don't see and http in the start or www just start with `/images`

Then in place `[1]` I see: `//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transparent.png`

Then after some items in place [10]  I see: http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@186000000&hl=iw&src=app&x=75&y=51&z=7&s=Gali

Im not sure what gali is I don't see `.bmp .gif` or `.png` images just Gali.

What I want is to download all the this images from each link and save it to my hard disk.
So I have this function for the download:

```
private Image GetImage(string url)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);

    System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(responseStream);

    responseStream.Dispose();

    return bmp;
}
```

When im using this GetImage function in the retrieveImages() function it dosent do anything the program even dosent owrk I mean the List imgList is empty. If I mark this two lines as it is now:

```
//Image imgDownload = GetImage(src.Value);
//imgDownload.Save(@"d:\myImages");
```

If I mark them with // not ot use them then evrything is working but if im using them nothing is working and its not saving anything to my hard disk.

What should I do?

Edit:

I just changed my retrieveImages function to this:

```
private List<string> retrieveImages(string address)
        {

            System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
            List<string> imgList = new List<string>();
            doc.Load(wc.OpenRead(address)); 
            HtmlNodeCollection imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]");
            if (imgs == null) return new List<string>();

            foreach (HtmlNode img in imgs)
            {
                if (img.Attributes["src"] == null)
                    continue;
                HtmlAttribute src = img.Attributes["src"];

                imgList.Add(src.Value);
                wc.DownloadFile(src.Value ,  @"d:\MyImages\my.gif");
            }
            return imgList;
        }
```

I used a breakpoint on the line wc.DownloadFile and it throw me an exception: Webexception Was Caught

Could not find a part of the path 'D:\textinputassistant\tia.png'.

In src.Value it waontin in this case: /textinputassistant/tia.png 
So you told me to avoid links that have not http or https or www in the start i will fix it.
The question is if the exception is since this line start with / and it dosent have any http/s/www ?

The full exception:

```
System.Net.WebException was caught
  Message=Could not find a part of the path 'D:\textinputassistant\tia.png'.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
       at GatherLinks.Form1.retrieveImages(String address) in D:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\Form1.cs:line 328
       at GatherLinks.Form1.webCrawler(String url, Int32 levels, DoWorkEventArgs eve) in D:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\Form1.cs:line 97
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       Message=Could not find a part of the path 'D:\textinputassistant\tia.png'.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
       InnerException: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
            Message=Could not find a part of the path 'D:\textinputassistant\tia.png'.
            Source=mscorlib
            StackTrace:
                 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
                 at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
                 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
                 at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
                 at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
```

### InnerException:

Just added a filter so it will save only links that start with http:

```
private List<string> retrieveImages(string address)
        {

            System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
            List<string> imgList = new List<string>();
            doc.Load(wc.OpenRead(address));
            HtmlNodeCollection imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]");
            if (imgs == null) return new List<string>();

            foreach (HtmlNode img in imgs)
            {
                if (img.Attributes["src"] == null)
                    continue;
                HtmlAttribute src = img.Attributes["src"];

                imgList.Add(src.Value);
                if (src.Value.Contains("http"))
                {
                    wc.DownloadFile(src.Value, @"d:\MyImages\my.gif");
                }
            }
            return imgList;
        }
```

Now src.Value contain: http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@186000000&hl=iw&src=app&x=75&y=51&z=7&s=Gali

Then after it trying to download im getting exception: WebException Was Caught

The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

```
System.Net.WebException was caught
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
       at GatherLinks.Form1.retrieveImages(String address) in D:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\Form1.cs:line 330
       at GatherLinks.Form1.webCrawler(String url, Int32 levels, DoWorkEventArgs eve) in D:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\Form1.cs:line 97
  InnerException:
```

The question is if the exception throw up since the site in this case google is blocking downloads or since the link end with Gali wich is im not sure what type of file it is ?

Comment: I believe that exception is due to the image path not containing a valid URL ie no http:// or www.

If you can, give it a shot with a different link and see how it works please

Comment: Andrew tried with another link edited my question again. This time im getting forbiden 403 exception.

Comment: Hm, that 403 error is unexpected. I assume you if you open up a browser the blue square shows up? 

I'll fire up a visual studio project and see if I can replicate the 403 over here

Comment: Andrew yes if im going to this link of google  i see blue square . The question what should i di in cases with this sites ? Is there any way to solve it sites with links that end with Gali or not start with http/s or www or just to use try and catch and not using this sites for now ?

Comment: I get the same 403 error from here so I don't think it's anything related to your network or anything.

I would recommend wrapping the code inside GetImage in a try/catch and swallowing or logging somewhere those errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first ignore images that don't have a valid link ie no http://

For saving a file right to disk you can download the binary for it and save like so:

```
string URL="http://www.yourdomain.com/file1.zip";
string DestinationPath="C:\file1.jpg";
System.Net.WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.DownloadFile(URL,DestinationPath);
```

You don't have to convert an image to a .net Image to save it. I have some similiar code in some import apps I wrote recently

Comment: Andrew Walters i tried it and got exception/s i just updated my question please look at it.

Comment: Andrew ok i added a filter so it will try to download only links that start with http. Now im getting another exception forbiden 403. I will update my question again.

Comment: Ok i tried another site now and its working: http://www.ynet.co.il/PicServer2/24012010/3072784/44.gif The question is if the problem before in google.com was the link end with Gali or forbiden 403 means google are blocking and downloads ?

Comment: And How should i handle this cases like google.com ? To use try and catch over the wc.DownloadFile ? I mean i have try and catch but is that a good way to avoid this exception to be throw up ?